Calculate the segment $AC$ in the secant circles below
In the figure, $AR =a$, and $CS = b$.
Calculate $AC$, with $M$, $N$, $R$ and S points of tangency.
(Answer:$\sqrt{a^2+b^2)}$

Itry:
Let $R$ be the radius of the largest circle and $r$ of the smallest
$a^2 = AM(AM+2R)$
$b^2 = CN(CN+2r)$
$CM^2 = (CN+r)(CN+2r)$
$CM^2 = (CN+r).\frac{b^2}{CN}$


Since $\angle AMC=\angle ANC=90^o$ then points A, M, N and C are on a circle on diameter AC. For the same reason point B, M , K and N are on a circle on diameter BK.
Power of A to circle t: $AR^2=AM\times AB$ =Power of A to circle v
Power of B to circle c: $BS^2=BN\times BC$=Power of B to circle v
Cicle m with radius CS intersects the circle n with radius AR at H.BI is the radical axis of these two circle and is perpendicular on AC . Clearly a circle with diameter AC passes H, this indicates the triangle HAC is rightangled and we have:
$AH^2+CH^2=AC^2$
AH=AR  and CH=CS so we have:
$AR^2+CS^2=AC^2=a^2+b^2$
OR:
$AC=\sqrt {a^2+b^2}$

Thanks for hel.p.  Can you explain betrer $AR^2+CS^2=AH^2+CH^2$?

@petaarantes, you are welcome, I edited my answer and explained more.

thanks for help
